# How strong is Hatchiyack in Dragon Ball?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes, dragon-ball-movies

IIRC, Hatchiyack in the OVA plan to eradicate the saiyans was able to fight Piccolo, Goku SSJ, Gohan SSJ, Vegeta SSJ and Trunks SSJ? How strong is he supposed to be compared to saiyans now in Dragon Ball Heroes and before in his first appearence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the movie, Goku states that he was probably stronger than *Broly at full Power* (Note: This is with reference to the non-canon iteration of Legendary Super Saiyan Broly).

With reference to DBH, in the manga, he is indicated to be stronger than Majin Ozotto. However, in the game, he is indicated to be much stronger and it takes the combined efforts of Majin Ozotto, Future Trunks and Cooler to defeat him